# Is it possible to ignore one type of push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

The problem is that I want to make ios client responsible for taking care of displaying/not displaying push notification relating on some kind type in push dictionary.

I would present some kind of modal view where user can choose what notifications he want to see.

And the question is it possible to ignore that chosen type when app is turned off or in background?

I know it's bad solution due to unnecessary unwanted pushes to be send and drain battery and it surely should be managed on the server side, but for now I need very fast solution that would be replaced in the future or even there could be double side check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No this is not possible, the push notification is handled by the system and not you app.

You only option is to use the background refresh with an background fetch push notification. This way you can handle the push notification in the background, and use `UILocalNotification` to push a notification in the notification center.

This a has draw back when some one has turned off the background update for your app.

The best way is to do it server side, just push the settings to you server and make the decision whether or not to send push notification bast on these settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what i thought. Unfortunately our server team doesn't belong to fastest ones - that's why I wanted to try to make it on the app side

Left with no good option - I need to ask them to make it quick :)